# Showing $R$ is a local ring if and only if all elements of $R$ that are not units form an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

My question is how would I go about proving this?

> Prove that $R$ is a local ring if and only if all elements of R that are not units form an ideal.

I understand that I need to prove both directions so:

$(\Rightarrow)$ Local ring means has a unique maximal ideal, so I want to show that this implies the elements are not units.

$(\Leftarrow)$ non unit elements of $R$ form an ideal, so if I show this is unique maximal ideal I can then conclude local ring?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the fact that any non-unit is contained in a maximal ideal?

Comment: I'm not, so i think that is what i need to be able to prove in my answer?

Comment: Using the axiom of choice, you can show that every non-unit lies in a maximal ideal. Now, this exercize is a direct consequence of this fact.

Comment: From the context it looks like you are assuming a commutative ring. Actually, the statement still holds for noncommutative rings (although the solutions given so far all seem to rely on a fact that holds for commutative rings and not all noncommutative rings.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book "*Introduction to Commutative Algebra*" by *Atiyah-Macdonald* has in Corollary 1.5:

> Every non-unit of $R$ is contained in a maximal ideal.

So
Let $R$ be local. If $m$ is the only maximal of $R$, then $m$ will be the set of non-units.
Conversely:
Let $n$ be the set of non-units of $R$. Let $m$ be a proper ideal s.t. $n\subseteq m$. Since $m$ is proper, no element of $m$ would be unit and so $m\subseteq n$. So $n$ is maximal.

---

Update:
This is also [lemma 3.13](https://books.google.com/books?id=Oi4x9NznFEUC&pg=PA41&dq=only+if+the+set+of+non-units+of+R+is+an+ideal&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJqM2Kz4vLAhWBqXIKHUCCD0cQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book "Steps in Commutative Algebra" by "Sharp" (in that terminology quasi-local means your "local".