# Local Ring with an another definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

We define a local ring with :

> The sum of any two non-units in $R$ is a non-unit.

And we want to show that :

> If $A$ is a local ring so $A$ has a unique maximal ideal (set of non-units).

I know how to show that the set of non-units is an ideal but maximal? 
I have an idea :
Let $A$ a commutative ring and $K$ the set of non-units

 We know that: $$ (x)=A \iff x \notin K    $$
                    $$ (x) \neq A \iff x \in K. $$

Krull's Theorem asserts that a nonzero ring has at least one maximal ideal.
So $K$ is an maximal ideal?

Comment: Suppose an ideal $I$ contains a unit $u$. What follows about $I$?

Comment: I is generated by u and ?

Comment: Don't worry about generators. An ideal containing a unit is … what?

Comment: If an ideal contained a unit so I=A (the ring) ?

Comment: Right. So every proper ideal of $A$ contains only non-units, and therefore …

Comment: K must be maximal ?

Comment: Well, yes, but what is the argument for that?

Comment: By definition of maximal ideal , no ?

Comment: You probably have the (well, one) right argument in your mind, but you haven't spelled it out yet. Maybe you think it's obvious - and in some sense it is - but it needs to be stated in a proof.

Comment: I just begin study of ring  and I'm not used to it. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Since you  "just begin study of ring", *maybe* [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1667100/showing-r-is-a-local-ring-if-and-only-if-all-elements-of-r-that-are-not-unit/1667139#1667139) can be a help.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer how do you suggest to show that the set of non units is an ideal in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've pretty much figured it out.  I'm gonna write out the details anyway because that's just what I like to do.

In any commutative ring $R$ with identity, an ideal $J$ of $R$ is proper (that is, $J$ is not equal to the whole ring) if and only if $J$ does not contain any units.  Certainly an ideal without units is proper.  Conversely if $J$ does contain a unit $u$, then $1 = u^{-1}u \in J$, hence for any $a \in R$, you have $a = a \cdot 1 \in J$.  Thus $R = J$, so $J$ is not proper.

If $R$ is a local ring, then the set $I$ of nonunits of $R$ is an ideal, as you've shown.  It also must be a maximal ideal: the only way $I$ could be any bigger is if it contained a unit, in which case $I$ would not be a proper ideal, and maximal ideals are by definition proper.

Finally, there cannot be any other maximal ideals besides $I$: if $M$ is any maximal ideal of $R$, then $M$ is proper, and so $M$ cannot contain any units.  Hence $M \subseteq I$, which implies $M = I$, because $M$ is a maximal ideal.