# Set of zero divisors is an ideal iff the ring is local

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Show that $Z(R)$, the set of all zero divisors of $R$, is an ideal if and only if $R$ is a local ring.

I have no idea for proving this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I know the reason for the down vote??

Comment: It was not me, but no effort on your side seems to show up. You can start out from the definitions.

Comment: Don't know. I upvoted, in reaction. Is a local ring noetherian, in your conventions?

Comment: no it is not noetherian @Bernard

Comment: If you put your cursor over the downvote arrow, part of the message that appears is "This question does not show any research effort". I think this is an adequate description of your post and hence the downvote, in my opinion, is justified.

Comment: Thus it is strictly forbidden to have no idea on how to tackle a problem?

Comment: The problem is that neither implication is true, and no attempt at context was made. Perhaps you meant [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1667100/29335) which is useful enough, but already asked?

Comment: @Bernard Counter upvotes (and counter downvotes) run contrary to what votes are supposed to achieve. Re your second comment, did you ever read some howtoask page?

Comment: One direction here is trivial to disprove, a nice familiar ring whose zero divisors form an ideal, yet which is not a local ring (unique maximal ideal).   Definitions are your friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *if* is false.

*Counter-example:*

Let $K$ be a field. consider the ring $R=\bigl(K[X,Y]/(XY)\bigr)_{(X,Y)}$. This ring is local by construction, has dimension $1$,  and its zero divisors is the union of its two minimal prime ideals, generated by (the images of) $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

*Added* (thanks to an idea of @rschwieb):

The *only if* part is false too:

Consider a *non-local* domain $D$ and a non-zero torsion-free $D$-module $M$. The set $R=D\times M$, endowed with the ring structure defined by
$$\begin{cases}(d,m)+(d',m')=(d+d',m+m')\\
(d,m)(d',m')=(dd',dm'+d'm)
\end{cases}$$
is a counter-example.

For ease of notation, we identify the ideal $\{0\}\times M$ with $M$. It's straightforward to check that $M^2=\{0\}$ and $Z(R)=M$. However, as $M$ is nilpotent, the spectra of $R$ and of $D$ are in bijection, hence $R$ is non-local.

Comment: +1 But you should also say that the *only if* is false too. In any nonlocal domain, the set of zero divisors is an ideal, and yet the ring isn't local.

Comment: @rschwied: Perhaps the O.P. means the case where there are non-trivial zero-divisors.

Comment: Then you just take a nonzero ideal $M$ of a nonlocal domain $D$ and form the ring structure on $D\times M$ given by $(d,m)+(d',m')=(d+d',m+m')$ and $(d,m)(d',m')=(dd', dm'+md')$ whose ideal $(0, M)$ is the set of all zero divisors, and still isn't local.

Comment: Fine! I'll add it, if you're not opposed.

Comment: Not opposed at all :)

Comment: @rschwieb: Updated. I've slightly generalised the construction. Thanks again for your idea!

Comment: You need to add that $M$ is torsionfree (which is why I picked a nonzero ideal) or else it is not true that $ZD(R)=(0,M)$.

Comment: Oh yes! I forgot this point. Fixed.Thanks!